# Multiple CSV inputs for URLs in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

We have several CSVs of URLs that we want to load using Apache JMeter.

The lists are `list-a.csv` and `list-b.csv`. Both contain just a single list of paths to test.

```
page
/section-a/page1.html
/section-a/page2.html
...
/section-a/pagen.html
```

and

```
page
/section-b/page1.html
/section-b/page2.html
...
/section-b/pagen.html
```

I need to be able to iterate through all those URLs.

I can get any one list to work using a `While Controller`, but the second list is never touched:

[image: Existing test]

I can get both lists executed if I put them in the same `While` loop, but then it only processes a number of records equal to the shorted list. (So if A is 100 records, and B is 10, only 10 of both lists are processed)

[image]

Comment: Currently one thread is hitting url from csv1 n times (configured in 1st while controller) and then similar stuff for 2nd csv in 2nd while. If you want both urls to be hitted one after another in sequence and in loop then later way is correct.

Comment: That's what I thought, but it doesn't work. Nothing from Section B is ever hit in the first layout.

Comment: You need to set the shorter list 'Recycle on EOF' to true, so it will keep looping as long as the longer list.

Comment: Also, try moving the CSV config to the test plan scope. Each time you reference a value, it will get the next from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the above jmeter behaviors are correct as it is because you set 'True' for 'Stop Thread on EOF?'.

**First Case:**

Thread is getting stopped once it finishes the first while loop, so it does not even go to second while loop

**Second Case**

One of the CSV data set config (whichever has minimum records) stops the thread once it finishes all the rows even if there is another csv data set config with more records.

**Workaround**

If there is no strict requirement to use while loop, You can configure as given below. It works fine for me.

Test Plan

[image]

Select this checkbox in the test plan config

[image]

Select 'Forever' for each Thread group - As CSV dataset config will stop the thread once it finishes all the rows.

[image]